# Body Background moves without the content

Tags: css, internet-explorer

In Internet Explorer the background of the webpage moves without the rest of the page's content, I need the background to be fixed with the content, so when I resize it the background doesn't move, like the content inside it, here is the link to the website:
[Website Link](http://henrynorthen.com/exp/scarywowotlk/index.html)

This error only appears in Internet Explorer. I have an internet explorer-only stylesheet you can view in the source of the website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe instead of (or in addition to) position: fixed, you can use

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Hope that helps.